# Installing ros2 on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ros2, c++

Recently, I wanted to try installing ros2 on ubuntu 23.04 or later versions. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ROS is not yet distributed as debians afaik: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html

Have a look at the [install from source](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html) instructions of the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install Docker on your U23.04?

If so follow my steps for installing ROS 2 on PiOS Bookworm

https://github.com/slowrunner/pi5desk/tree/main/configs/docker